# How can I query one record / result based on uid in graphiQL with gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS which has GraphQL as a part of it. I am new to both. And for the life of me I can not figure out how to query for a single record using graphql via a uid value.
I have a simple json file. In GraphiQL the output of this query....

```
query{
  allDataJson{
    edges {
      node {
        products{
          uid
          sku
          title 
          price
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gives me all the records..

```
{
  "data": {
    "allDataJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "products": [
              {
                "uid": 0,
                "sku": "8509698P",
                "title": "Cindy Crawford Home Bellingham Slate Sofa",
                "price": 655,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/cindy-crawford-home-bellingham-slate-sofa_8509698P_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 1,
                "sku": "10132859",
                "title": "Sofia Vergara Pacific Palisades Navy Plush Sofa",
                "price": 799.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/sofia-vergara-pacific-palisades-navy-sofa_10132859_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 2,
                "sku": "15028930",
                "title": "Eric Church Highway To Home Headliner Brown Leather Dual Power Reclining Sofa",
                "price": 1599.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/eric-church-highway-to-home-headliner-brown-leather-power-plus-reclining-sofa_15028930_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 3,
                "sku": "10141620",
                "title": "Bonita Springs Gray Sofa",
                "price": 499.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/bonita-springs-gray-sofa_10141620_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 4,
                "sku": "14103941",
                "title": "Villa Capri Blue Leather Sofa",
                "price": 899.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/villa-capri-blue-leather-sofa_14103941_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 5,
                "sku": "8509697P",
                "title": "Cindy Crawford Home Bellingham Indigo Sofa",
                "price": 655,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/cindy-crawford-home-bellingham-indigo-sofa_8509697P_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 6,
                "sku": "8509695P",
                "title": "Cindy Crawford Home Bellingham Cardinal Microfiber Sofa",
                "price": 655,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/cindy-crawford-home-bellingham-cardinal-sofa_8509695P_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 7,
                "sku": "10132950",
                "title": "Cindy Crawford Home Chelsea Hills Gray Sofa",
                "price": 799.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/cindy-crawford-home-chelsea-hills-gray-sofa_10132950_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 8,
                "sku": "10197704",
                "title": "Ivyleigh Silver Sofa",
                "price": 599.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/ivyleigh-silver-sofa_10197704_image.png?w=150"
              },
              {
                "uid": 9,
                "sku": "10131403",
                "title": "Court Street Beige Sofa",
                "price": 599.99,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/court-street-beige-sofa_10131403_image.png?w=150"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I query for a single uid???

```
query{
  allDataJson(filter: ??? ){
    edges {
      node {
        products{
          uid
          sku
          title 
          price
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so that my results are something like this???

```
{
  "data": {
    "allDataJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "products": [
              {
                "uid": 0,
                "sku": "8509698P",
                "title": "Cindy Crawford Home Bellingham Slate Sofa",
                "price": 655,
                "image": "https://images.rtg-prod.com/cindy-crawford-home-bellingham-slate-sofa_8509698P_image.png?w=150"
              },
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: filter the `products` something like `products(uid: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the id in query args and BE should return only single record based on the id. Like below.

```
query{


allDataJson(id:1 ){
    edges {
      node {
        products{
          uid
          sku
          title 
          price
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant uid:1 yes? Either way, I tried both uid and id(just for fun)....I get this error message..."message": "Unknown argument \"uid\" on field \"allDataJson\" of type \"Query\"."....I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

GraphiQL should also suggest the query `dataJson` to you. While `allDataJson` gives you back a connection (hence the array), `dataJson` only returns a single result - often used with a filter.

So something like this should work (I couldn't try it in GraphiQL myself):

```
query {
  dataJson(products: { uid: { eq: 2 } }) {
    products {
      uid
    }
  }
}
```

Please try it yourself with the auto-completion of GraphiQL.

Comment: I get this error "message": "Field \"uid\" is not defined by type DataJsonProductsFilterListInput.",.....I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed out the filter function of graphql in Gatsby, but your case is a bit different: your product is an array. By default, there's no way you can filter the array returned by a field -- each item in the array has to be a node.

It'll be much easier if you can transform your data structure from this:

```
// data.json
{
  products: [{ "uid": 0 }, { "uid": 1 }]
}
```

...to something like this:

```
// data.json
[{ "uid": 0 }, { "uid": 1 }]
```

...and store your metadata somewhere else.

This way, each item in the array will become a node, and you can filter like expected.

```
{
  allDataJson(filter: {
    uid: {eq: 1}
  }) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If changing the json data structure is not possible, you can also write your own `gatsby-transformer-json` that simply read the json file & create a node for each item in the product list.